# In Android, How to check if my params contains the value image

Tags: java, android, arrays, if-statement, conditional-statements

In Android, How to check if my params contains the value image

here is the params output :

```
["image=fdfdsgdg5dsgd1s211511", "id=dfd4f5d4f5d", "api_id=f4f54f5d454df"]
```

Code:

```
public String getQueryString(List<NameValuePair> params) {
    Log.d(TAG, "getQueryString - params => " + params);
    String queryString = "";
    Iterator<NameValuePair> itr = params.iterator();    

    while(itr.hasNext()) {
        NameValuePair nvp = itr.next();         

        //TODO if ....
        try {
            if(Arrays.asList(params).contains("image")) {
                Log.w(TAG, "if(Arrays.asList(params).contains('image'))");

                break;
            }
```

Comment: Simply do `if(params.contains("image"))`...

Answer (score 0):

It has the method getName() and getValue() 
See : [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/NameValuePair.html#getName())

Answer (score 0):

*Try this*

```
while (itr.hasNext()) {
            NameValuePair nvp = itr.next();

            if (nvp.getName().equals("image")
                    && nvp.getValue().equals("fdfdsgdg5dsgd1s211511")) {
                return nvp.getName()+" "+nvp.getValue()+" Exists";

            }
            if (nvp.getName().equals("id")
                    && nvp.getValue().equals("dfd4f5d4f5d")) {
                return nvp.getName()+" "+nvp.getValue()+" Exists";

            }
            if (nvp.getName().equals("api_id")
                    && nvp.getValue().equals("f4f54f5d454df")) {
                return nvp.getName()+" "+nvp.getValue()+" Exists";

            }

        }
```